# Under which circumstances is a rollback appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Specifically: https://askubuntu.com/posts/308263/revisions.

It looks like revision #3 (inadvertedly) reverted revision #2 - would that be a case for a rollback?

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 came through in review. The proposed revision was to remove the word `export` and add the word `install`. I didn't agree with removing `export`, so I hit <kbd>Improve</kbd> and only added `install`. So there was really only 1 revision.

Comment: understood, I overlooked the fact that you were aware of the suggested edit. Still my question remains - this was just a bad example.

Comment: It felt awkward while I was doing it since it turned into my edit and I didn't see a way to explain to the proposed editor what I was doing. I just crossed 2k this past week and am new to the Suggested Edit queue, so if there is something else I should have done please just let me know.

Comment: I am still learning myself - but if you think a suggestion is wrong you can either *reject* it or uncheck the "was helpful" box. In the latter case it is only your edit and the suggestor gets no rep from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. :)